# Why datasnapshot loops are out of order?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm iterating data from children from Firebase Realtime Database [Click to view Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2FhD.png), but for some reason the loops iterating order is not logical to me.

Meaning that after checking the code below the log should show:

**[XRA, 32-LY-14, 2, 1, 32-LY-15, 3, 2, YRa, 33-LY-77, 4, 3]**

but it shows:

**[XRA, YRa, 32-LY-14, 2, 1, 32-LY-15, 3, 2, 33-LY-77, 4, 3]**

Also if I put Log.d("TAG", DrawingsList.toString()); after finishing the DataSnapshot loops then Arraylist appears empty as if nothing is added to it.

```
 public void Drawings_71 () {
    DrawingsList.clear();
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Drawings").child("Area 71").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                TAG = ds.getKey();
                DrawingsList.add(TAG);
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Drawings").child("Area 71").child(TAG).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot2) {
                        for (DataSnapshot ds2 : dataSnapshot2.getChildren()) {
                           String TAG2 = ds2.getKey();
                            String Current_Version = ds2.child("Current Version").getValue().toString();
                            String Previous_Version = ds2.child("Previous Version").getValue().toString();
                            DrawingsList.add(TAG2);
                            DrawingsList.add(Current_Version);
                            DrawingsList.add(Previous_Version);
                        }
                        Log.d("TAG", DrawingsList.toString());
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The outer loop is completing before the inner loop.  That's because the call to  `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` is asynchronous and returns immediately before its callback is ever invoked.  So what you've done is kick off a bunch of listeners for child values, but none of them are going to complete faster than the entire iteration through the outer loop.  This is to be expected with the code as you've written it here.

It sounds like you also might be unaware that your inner listeners are unnecessary here, as the outer listener snapshot actually contains all of the data under "/Drawings/Area 71".  If you just dig into that `dataSnapshot` a little more carefully, you won't have to query each of the children separately.

Comment: I will check the addListenerForSingleValueEvent to fix this issue. If I don't include the inner loop then I should a listener for each child inside "/Drawings/Area 71" and I'm going to have hundreds of data so I'm trying to iterate it, if there is any other way to do that I'll be glad to useit.

Comment: As I said, you don't need to add a listener for each child.  All the data is already in the first snapshot. The query was deep and included all children, and all their children.

Comment: But I need get the data from the children of children, I can't figure out how to do it using the first snapshot only. Anyway I will try to figure it out, thanks for the tips.

Comment: DataSnapshot has a method called getValue() that you should be using. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot

Answer (score 0):

When you attach a listener to a certain reference, the Firebase client downloads all data under that reference. So your listener on `Drawings/Area 71` already contains all data that exists under that node, including the data for each child node. In fact, I'm pretty sure `ds2` and `ds` are snapshots of the same data.

A simpler way to get the data is:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Drawings").child("Area 71").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            TAG = ds.getKey();
            DrawingsList.add(TAG);

            String Current_Version = ds.child("Current Version").getValue().toString();
            String Previous_Version = ds.child("Previous Version").getValue().toString();
            DrawingsList.add(TAG2);
            DrawingsList.add(Current_Version);
            DrawingsList.add(Previous_Version);
        }
        System.out.println("Loaded: "+DrawingsList.size())
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
});
```

Comment: but this will get me the direct child, in this case it won;t check the current version from the inner child